# Recode a range of values into one number using 'recode()' in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

I am working with a very messy data set and I'll be needing to use the recode() function in a pipe to turn numbers 0:30 into four numerical categories (0,1,2,3,4).

What I have:

```
recode(var, 10:30 = 4,
              6:9 = 3,
              3:5 = 2,
              1:2 = 1,
              0 = 0))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(var %in% 10:30 ~ 4,
               var %in% 6:9 ~ 3, 
               var %in% 3:5 ~ 2,
               var %in% 1:2 ~ 1, 
                var == 0 ~ 0)
```

---

Or another option is `cut`

```
as.integer(cut(var, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 2, 5, 9, 30, Inf)))
```

NOTE: change the `include.lowest` and `right` option in `cut` to adjust

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
var <- sample(0:35, 50, replace = TRUE)
```